# What are some methods for returning a subset of resources user is authorized to access with a REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, web-applications, authorization

Say I have an endpoint: `/task` that returns `task` resources.

It's an endpoint that all authenticated users are authorized to hit, but it should only return the subset of `tasks` that the user has access to (created by, owned, or shared with).

I don't want to offload this to query parameters and expect the client to filter on the user ID.

What are some methods for handling this?

Are there any using Auth0 or other 3rd party authorization services?

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful way to handle this is to nest the endpoint as so: `/user/{id}/task`.

Secure the endpoint and only allow authenticated users to hit it.

Then validate that the id in the URI matches the requesting user, or that the user is an admin. If the token contains the user id in the payload, could be just a simple check that it matches the id in the URI.

Same thing could be done at an endpoint such as `/user/{id}/task/{taskid}`. But an additional check would need to ensure that the given user is the owner of that task.